# Snap thinks snap-store directory is not a directory

Tags: snap-store

Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I try to launch the Software app, but it never comes up. In `/var/log/syslog` I find: `"snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop[17496]: cannot create user data directory: /home/steve/snap/snap-store/599: Not a directory"`

However:

```
$ file /home/steve/snap/snap-store/599
/home/steve/snap/snap-store/599: directory
```

This seems like a pretty fundamental bug, but I don't see others reporting it. What gives? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the output of `realptah /home/steve/snap/snap-store/599`?

Comment: ~$ realpath /home/steve/snap/snap-store/599
/disk2/steve/snap/snap-store/599~$ file /disk2/steve/snap/snap-store/599
/disk2/steve/snap/snap-store/599: directory
~$

Comment: The ptoblem is that it's not your home directory, snap-store cannot access tis location, hence the error. Maybe it works if you mount the drive somewhere under `/media` and grant the snap permissions to access removable media. If not, keep the folder in your home directory.

Comment: It IS my home directory:
~$ ls -l /home
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 steve steve 12 Feb  2  2022 steve -> /disk2/steve
Everything is there, and it's accessible by anyone and everyone. There is no reason snap can't access it.

Comment: Your /home is not a directory at all, it is a symlink and this is the reason why any snap will complain not beeing able to access it. Snaps are confined and do not have access to any location outside /home. That's why I asked for realpath output. If you don't believe that and think it's a bug, file a bug-report.

Comment: /home is not a directory, but /home/steve/snap/snap-store/599 is a directory, in spite of what the syslog message claims.<br/>So this is an intentional limitation of snap? Wonderful.